# return 0 for items count in linq statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Lets say I have the following EF6 Linq statement which counts number of items for 2 tables (Table1 has 10 items and Table2 has no items) :

```
var q = db.Table1.GroupBy(g => "Table1").Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, EntryCount = g.Count() })
          .Union(db.Table2.GroupBy(g => "Table2").Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, EntryCount = g.Count() }));

var r = q.ToList();
```

The expected result should be something like

```
Name    | EntryCount
---------------------
Table1  |   10
Table2  |    0
```

However because Table2 doesn't have any items it doesn't appear in the final result and I get the following:

```
Name    | EntryCount
---------------------
Table1  |   10
```

How can I make sure Table 2 always appear in the final list even if its empty and doesn't have any records?

To give you a background on why I am doing this Linq statement , I am converting the following TSQL statement into a linq query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetLookups] ()
RETURNS
@lookupsWithItemCounts TABLE 
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [EntryCount] INT
)

AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @lookupsWithItemCounts([Name],[EntryCount])
     VALUES
               ('Table1', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)),
               ('Table2', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)),
               ('Table3', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3))

    RETURN;
END
```

Also its very important to for this linq statement to run in one database trip, not multiple.

Comment: why not just do simple counts? i.e. `db.Table1.Count()` and `db.Table2.Count()`, and worry about the bundling later? this seems more likely to give you the results you want; indeed, any grouping over zero rows is zero groups, even if the grouping is an "all rows" grouping

Comment: why are you using union? seems like you can do something like this: ```var r = new[] { new { Name = "Table1", EntryCount = db.Table1.Count() }, new { Name = "Table2", EntryCount = db.Table2.Count() } };```

Comment: I am trying to come up with the linq equivalent of the TSQL statement I pasted.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I want the linq query to fetch the result from database in one trip and replace the TSQL function I have pasted. If this is not possible  in one single linq query then I am going to use the native sql function.

Comment: What if you added `DefaultIfEmpty()` before the `Select` for Table2?

Comment: @NetMage, Can you elaborate more on DefaultIfEmpty() by providing sample working code?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't appear to work with LINQ to SQL/EF... Your T-SQL statement executes multiple database queries and the literal translation to LINQ will also do that.

Comment: @NetMage, the sql statement is a function within sql sever and by calling it from database I only need to have a single trip to database. I dont want to call the database twice from the linq code.

Comment: @MHoos so... Write SQL? `select (select count(*) from A) as A, (select count(*) from B) as B`. Most ORMs make it trivial to run this kind of query, or it is perfect for tools like Dapper

Comment: FYI, experimenting with EF 3.0, it generates a single simple `UNION` SQL query that returns `0` rows for empty tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a default table with a single row in it.

```
var ans = Table1.GroupBy(u => "Table1")
                .Select(ug => new { Name = ug.Key, EntryCount = ug.Count() })
                .Union(Table2.GroupBy(l => "Table2")
                              .Select(lg => new { Name = lg.Key, EntryCount = lg.Count() })
                              .Union(OneRowTable.GroupBy(u2 => 1)
                                                .Select(u2g => new { Name = "Table2", EntryCount = u2g.Count()-1 }) )
                              .OrderByDescending(cg => cg.EntryCount)
                              .Take(1)
               );
```

This is evaluated in a single round trip to the database by LINQ to SQL. I can't easily test with LINQ to EF.

Note that in EF Core 3.0, the original query is translated in such a way as to return a `0` row for any empty tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of tables then table list can be used to `union` a row with `EntryCount = 0` and then on final result set a `GroupBy` on Name and `Sum` of `EntryCount` will provide desired result.

```
//List of tables
var tableList = new string[] { "Table1", "Table2" }; 

var res = db.Table1
    .GroupBy(t1 => "Table1")
    .Select(gt1 => new { Name = gt1.Key, EntryCount = gt1.Count()})
    .Union(db.Table2
           .GroupBy(t2 => "Table2")
           .Select(gt2 => new { Name = gt2.Key, EntryCount = gt2.Count()})
          )
    .Union(tableList
           .GroupBy(s => s)
           .Select(gs => new { Name = gs.Key, EntryCount = 0 })
          )
    .GroupBy(gg => gg.Name)
    .Select(fg => new {Name = fg.Key, EntryCount=fg.Select(ee => ee.EntryCount).Sum()})
       .ToList();
```

The result will have EntryCount for all tables in list.

Comment: When I tried variations of this, the `EntryCount = 0` was rejected by the LINQ to SQL translator.

Comment: Putting `AsEnumerable` there seems to work well, especially in EF 3.0 where it generates a very simple SQL query. Interestingly, the original simple query generates a `0` count record in EF 3.0 so working around it isn't needed.

Comment: Query with `Table2` with zero rows: `var ans = Table1
    .GroupBy(t1 => "Table1")
    .Select(gt1 => new { Name = gt1.Key, EntryCount = gt1.Count()})
    .Union(Table2
           .GroupBy(t2 => "Table2")
           .Select(gt2 => new { Name = gt2.Key, EntryCount = gt2.Count()})
          )`; Ran against MS SQL Server. Resulting SQL: `SELECT N'Users' AS [Name], COUNT(*) AS [EntryCount]
FROM [user] AS [u]
UNION
SELECT N'TblLogs' AS [Name], COUNT(*) AS [EntryCount]
FROM [tblLog] AS [t]
GO`.

Comment: I added note to my answer.